# Как сделать так, чтобы telegram бот не выключался из-за исключений?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу бота на `PyTelegramBotApi`. Запускаю его так `bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=120)`. Но не смотря на то, что `none_stop=True`, бот все-равно падает из-за иногда возникающих исключений (например `TimeoutException` или исключения связанные с работой бота). Как сделать так, чтобы он игнорировал все исключения и продолжал работать?

Answer (score 2):

Вот [тут](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/436) есть пример, который может помочь:

```
while True:
    try:
        logging.info("Bot running..")
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=2)

        # Предполагаю, что бот может мирно завершить работу, поэтому
        # даем выйти из цикла
        break
    except telebot.apihelper.ApiException as e:
        logging.error(e)
        bot.stop_polling()

        time.sleep(15)

        logging.info("Running again!")
```

Т.е. при выбрасывании исключения, мы его ловим, логируем и через n-времени запускаем бота

Comment: А если после этого произойдет еще одно исключение?

Comment: Хорошее замечание, нужно в цикл обернуть, щас покажу

Comment: получается, что даже если исключения не будет он все равно будет еще и еще раз выполнять bot.polling

Comment: не, код дальше polling не пойдет, пока этот метод не завершится, если у вас возникают подобные вопросы, то иногда полезно смотреть исходники, вот: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py#L317

Comment: спасибо. А вообще polling можно в продакшн использовать? Или обязательно webhooks? Просто telegram только на https отправляет, нужен сертификат.

Comment: Вот на этот вопрос, к сожалению, я не знаю ответа

Comment: сертификат можно сделать бесплатно, домен третьего уровня бесплатно у динамических днс)